# Kendo UI Grid displays [object Object]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have a class

```
public class LookupClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

That I have referenced in another class

```
public class Sampleclass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public LookupClass LookupEntry { get; set; }
}
```

which is is displayed in a KendoUI Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SampleClass>()
    .Name("SomeGrid")
    .Columns(cols => {
         cols.Bound(o => o.LookupEntry).Title("Lookup Column")  // Displays [object Object]
         cols.Bound(o => o.LookupEntry.Name) // displays name correctly
    }
    .DataSource(datasource => 
         // leaving this out since the data is seems to be loading correctly.
    )
)
```

When displaying the grid it just displays [object Object] for the value in the cells in the "Lookup Column" column.  I have gotten the editor template working (leaving out code since not necessary, basically copied from [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/documentation/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates)) and saving/loading works (left out for simplicity), but I can't seem to figure out how to display the Name property from the Lookup class.

Comment: Column binding works on a property and not on a class level, the reason you got that `[object Object]`.

Comment: On the Kendo UI site they have an example that uses the class level to do an editorTemplate with a dropdown, so I am assuming that there must be a way to make this display the class too.

Comment: I think there should be an editor template if you will be binding to a class, similar to if how you will do it in a view. You should probably check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a KendoUI example that shows how to do this (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html)

Basically you have to use a ClientTemplate to display the property you want to display

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SampleClass>()
    .Name("SomeGrid")
    .Columns(cols => {
         cols.Bound(o => o.LookupEntry).ClientTemplate("#=LookupEntry.Name#").Title("Lookup Column") 
    }
)
```

On a side note, if you try to create a new record, it will produce an error about not finding LookupEntry (don't remember exact message).  In the example listed, there is also a bit in the model section that shows how to set a default object.